# Duplicate page requests in wordpress admin

Tags: php, wordpress, http

I set a custom setting page in wordpress.

And when I visit that page, I add the counter in the database.

And eventually I found the counter increases by 3 after a single page view.

---

Moreover, I found any of the admin page has the same problem.

For example, the `/wp-admin/edit.php` requests more than once when I view that page, see the figure below.

[image: Duplicate request of admin pages]

What's the reason? How to prevent it? Please help!

Comment: It could be an ajax request?

Comment: Oh, thank you all, I finally know that was because of `<img src="" />` avatar image changed by a plugin. And everything goes fine after i removed the src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress does AJAX calls to admin-ajax.php in order to check if you're authenticated. But in a clean Wordpress installation(latest version) I haven't noticed any ajax request to edit.php.
I would throw the blame on a plugin installed, try disabling your plugins and see if the requests persist.

Also, check the headers of both of those requests, if there is at least one difference you can condition your counter to ignore the extra requests.